# Is there a nice way to simulate Android's Fragment Pattern in iOS?

Tags: cross-platform, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

We're using MvvmCross in our apps. In our Android app, we use the [NavigationDrawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for our Menu. We load our HomeView which contains the NavigationDrawer and the `ContentFrame`.

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_frame" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When the `OnCreate()` method is triggered, we load an AudioPlayerFragment into the `content_frame` based on a database query. In that same method we setup a listener that waits for the user to click one of the ListItem's in the navigation drawer.

```csharp
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   // do stuff to build the nav drawer
    _topDrawerList = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.left_drawer);
    _topDrawerList.ItemClick += (sender, args) = > SelectItem(args.Position, null);

    if(bundle == null)
        SelectItem(0, null);
}

private void SelectItem(int position, UserViewModel currentUser) {
    SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()...
}
```

Our app is working great, and I like how the HomeView is the only View for the app. Everything else is a Fragment.

In our Core library, we have a ViewModel for the HomeView, and we also have a ViewModel for each Fragment in the app. Again, this is working well for us.

> - PCL
>
>   - ViewModels
>
>     - HomeViewModel
>     - AudioPlayerViewModel  <-- vm for fragment
>     - LoginFragmentViewModel  <-- vm for fragment
> - Droid.Ui
>
>   - Fragments
>
>     - AudioPlayerFragment
>     - LoginFragment
>   - Views
>
>     - HomeView  <sup>*<-- Just a container View as the entry point to the app. Everything else is fragmented... AudioPlayerFragment is
>         loaded instantly.*</sup>

Now I'm trying to build a matching iOS app, but I can't figure out how to structure it. Essentially I'd like the exact same behavior where `HomeView` is the entry point and can contain both the SlidingPanel bits and some form of a ContentFrame that other "Views" can be loaded into.

Unfortunately, right now I've got this stupid MenuView to deal with, and a corresponding MenuViewModel... and I really don't want either.

> - PCL
>
>   - ViewModels
>
>     - HomeViewModel
>     - AudioPlayerViewModel  <-- vm for fragment
>     - LoginFragmentViewModel  <-- vm for fragment
> - Touch UI
>
>   - Views
>
>     - AudioPlayerView
>     - HomeView
>     - LoginView
>     - MenuView <sup>*<-- UGLY!!!*</sup>
>   - ViewModels
>
>     - MenuViewModel <sup>*<-- UGLY!!!*</sup>

I really don't want to create a custom View/ViewModel for the Menu. I'm using [SlidingPanels](https://github.com/patbonecrusher/SlidingPanels.Touch/tree/master/SlidingPanels/SlidingPanels.Lib) for my iOS "version" of the Navigation Drawer, and the tutorials I'm seeing are requiring an additional View/ViewModel for the menu.

Is there any way to do this and keep continuity with regards to ViewModels so that they can all be reused in a PCL? Is there a nice (read Clean) way to build the layout structure in a similar way to Android?

Comment: You can still reuse your HomeViewModel, but you're going to need a "HomeView" in which you can access the commands from the HomeViewModel and include SlidingPanels on ViewDidLoad(). You could always try FlyoutNavigation https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/FlyoutNavigation

Comment: @JonDouglas Ok, I do see how that FlyoutNavigation works. Will have to see how cleanly it would integrate with my app... good find.

Comment: One caveat is to not focus on making one platform "Like" the other. First rule of cross platform development is Android != iOS != Windows Phone. You will be able to re-use 70%+ of your code, but you will have to write some custom things for each platform(Mainly platform specific implementations). However in this case, you seem like you'll be able to make the iOS UI similar to Android. (NavigationDrawers)

Comment: @jondouglas that's the idea here. I am fully aware that each UI will have very different implementations, but there's no reason why viewmodels and commands shouldn't be 100% shared.

Comment: You can still fully share these viewmodels, but you're trying to push the NavigationDrawer UI into the apps which might seem like you can't share the viewmodels but you should be fine. Hit me up in jabbr if you need anymore help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I've settled on is to use the MvxViewController as my base entry point into the app.

```csharp
public class HomeView: MvxViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var myEntryFragement = new MyEntryFragment();
        Add(myEntryFragment);
    }
}
```

And then use `MvxView`'s as "Fragments"

```csharp
public class MyEntryFragment: MvxView // essentially a UIView
{

    private MyEntryViewModel _viewModel;
    public MyEntryFragment()
    {
        // manually construct the _viewModel (or alternatively inject it in the constructor)
        // setup all your UI controls in here
    }

}
```

Then I just load and unload my "Fragment's" as needed.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some attempts to provide unified User Interfaces driven by Portable code. Within MvvmCross, these have especially been driven by the `MonoTouch.Dialog` type approach to user interfaces. One such attempt/experiment is called "auto-views" - you can see it in action in:

- http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/recap-on-what-are-autoviews.html
- https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/AutoViewExamples

Beneath this autoviews layer, further View code can be shared quite readily within MvvmCross at the `Dialog` level - e.g. see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/DialogExamples

---

However... with this said... most of the auto-views work to date has still focused on provide rapid prototyping rather than finished apps. For a full **rich** user interface, most developers still provide custom UIs.

> I simply can't wrap my head around the iOS UI. It feels so very foreign to me in comparison to Android.

This isn't that unusual - most XAML developers take to AXML faster than they do to UIKit. However, if you take some time to build some `UIView`s and to build some user interfaces (pages) with `UIViewController`s, then I think you'll get the hang of UIKit quite quickly. Further, I'm confident that once you start seeing the code-based power of things like UIKit animations then you'll even start to fall in love!

Comment: Thanks for that @Stuart. Can you expand slightly on my main concern about the need for 2 ViewModels for iOS (one for nav menu, and one for   the rest of the view) vs 1 ViewModel for Droid (includes `IList` for nav as well as the rest of the view)?

Comment: A `ViewModel` is **just** a model for a view. You can aggregate your display between as many views (and behind-the-scenes `ViewModel`s) as you like. Maybe take a look at something like N=32 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/ - it frees you away from thinking of `ViewModel`'s in terms of units of navigation (well, it tries to...)

Comment: Thanks Stuart. N32 pointed me down the path I eventually decided to go. I've accepted my own answer as it is a direct answer to the question, but awarded you the bounty... Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to reuse your View Models, but not your Views. Today, PCL doesn't provide access to the UI stack, so you can't have portable views. For more details, have a look at the blog post [How to Make Portable Class Libraries Work for You](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx) that our tester wrote.

Comment: I don't intend on reusing my Views. But I do want 100% portability of my ViewModels. As I see it now however, my HomeViewModel contains properties for both my page title and stuff, as well as the navigation menu, but I can't see a way to do that same thing in iOS SlidingPanels menu. It "appears" as though I need a separate ViewModel for the menu and the "other bits"